# Access to Java object fields in Flex BlazeDS

Tags: java, apache-flex, object, field, blazeds

I'm using BlazeDS to connect Flex with Java. I'm having trouble when i try to access to java object fields in Flex

it's my Java class Path:

```
package intetech;

public class Path {

    public Path(){

    }
    public Path(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2){
        this.x1 = x1;
        this.y1 = y1;
        this.x2 = x2;
        this.y2 = y2;
    }

    public double getX1(){
        return x1;
    }
    public double getY1(){
        return y1;
    }
    public double getX2(){
        return x2;
    }
    public double getY2(){
        return y2;
    }

    private double x1;
    private double y1;
    private double x2;
    private double y2;
}
```

And Java class PathsService which returns ArrayList of Path in getPaths method:

```
package intetech;

import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class PathsService {
    public PathsService(){}

    public List<Path> getPaths(){
        File svgFile = new File("D:\\work\\blazedsTurnkey\\blazeds-turnkey-4.0.0.14931\\tomcat\\webapps\\blazeds\\WEB-INF\\classes\\intetech\\test.svg");
        try{
            SvgParser svgp = new SvgParser(svgFile);
            listOtr = svgp.getList();
        } catch (SAXException ex) {

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException ex) {

        } catch (IOException ex) { }

        return listOtr;
    }

    private static List<Path> listOtr;
}
```

So I try to get coordinates of one path from ArrayList in flex. 
 Main.mxml:

```
  <fx:Declarations>
    <!--setup the connection to the Java class-->
    <mx:RemoteObject
        id="PathsService"
        destination="pathsservice"
        showBusyCursor="true"
        >

        <mx:method name="getPaths" 
                   result="resultGetPaths(event)" 
                   fault="faultGetPaths(event)"/>



    </mx:RemoteObject>
</fx:Declarations>



<fx:Script>
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.controls.Alert;
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
        import mx.utils.ObjectUtil;



        private var aPath:Path ;
        private var pathsArrCol:ArrayCollection;
        private var otr:Path;


        public function resultGetPaths(event:ResultEvent):void {

            pathsArrCol = event.result as ArrayCollection;
            **otr = pathsArrCol.getItemAt(0) as Path;
            Alert.show(ObjectUtil.toString(otr.getX1()));** 
        } 


        private function faultGetPaths(event:FaultEvent):void{

            Alert.show( ObjectUtil.toString(event.fault) );


        }

</fx:Script>
```

and Path.as file:

```
package
{
    [RemoteClass(alias="intetech.Path")]

[Bindable]
public class Path
{

    private var ax1:Number;
    private var ay1:Number;
    private var ax2:Number; 
    private var ay2:Number;




    public function getX1():Number {
        return ax1;
    }
    public function getY1():Number {
        return ay1;
    }
    public function getX2():Number {
        return ax2;
    }
    public function getY2():Number {
        return ay2;
    }



public function setX1(data:Number): void{
        ax1 = data;
    }
    public function setY1(data:Number): void{
        ax1 = data;
    }
    public function setX2(data:Number): void{
        ax1 = data;
    }
    public function setY2(data:Number): void{
        ax1 = data;
    }

}
}
```

I have NaN result when i run this application, please help

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any public setters/getters in your flex object:

```
package {

    [RemoteClass(alias="intetech.Path")]
    [Bindable]
    public class Path {

        private var ax1:Number;
        private var ay1:Number;
        private var ax2:Number; 
        private var ay2:Number;

        public function get x1():Number {
            return ax1;
        }

        public function get y1():Number {
            return ay1;
        }

        public function get x2():Number {
            return ax2;
        }

        public function get y2():Number {
            return ay2;
        }

        public function set x1(data:Number):void {
            ax1 = data;
        }

        public function set y1(data:Number):void {
            ay1 = data;
        }

        public function set x2(data:Number):void {
            ax2 = data;
        }

        public function set y2(data:Number):void {
            ay2 = data;
        }

    }
}
```

The result is that BlazeDS cannot properly initialize your new Flex object with the serialized data from Java.

Comment: Please, can you explain me, i add 4 setters for every coordinate x1,x2,y1,y2  and nothing happen

Comment: Notice the difference between your setters and mine?  Actionscript is not the same as Java ;)  You'll also need getters to match the Java setters.  I'll update my answer to include a new proposed implementation for your Flex Object.

Comment: Wow! It's works! Thanks! But how BlazeDS understands which set method is needed for required field?

Comment: @goodspeed it uses the setter that matches the name of the java property it's trying to set, based on what the serialization process extracted from your Java object.

Comment: i set all private modificators to public and remove all getters and setters, and it works, but it's not a solution i guess

Comment: You lost me @goodspeed, if all you did to your code above is made the flex properties public, then BlazeDS would never match up your Java property of `x1` to flex property of `ax1`.  So...

Comment: i set my flex property from ax1 to x1 and BlazeDS matchs, also i set private modificators in java to public too

Comment: where are you, @Daedalus?   I still need your help